# Mobaxterm terminal display adjustment

Tags: terminal, xterm, mobaxterm

For MobaXTerm on windows it defaults to showing date and time on every line, I can't seem to find the setting to disable this - does anyone know?

[Link to how it shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsMjj.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, use classic .bashrc file mechanism:

1. Create or open ~/.bashrc.perso,
2. Change or add the entry 'PS1=' with your desired value see for example the following web site to select your selectors "https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html" E.g. PS1="\u>" (no more that PS1="..." in the text line) to have only your login plus the '>' character as your new prompt,
3. Save the file and exit it,
4. Create a new tab, you can see that your new prompt is as desired.

Or simply, execute the line PS1="..." (E.g. PS1="[\e[35m]\w[\e[0m] [\e[36m][\u.\h][\e[0m] [\e(0]b[\e(B]") in each terminal you want a specific prompt.